# How to grep by section in a file?

Tags: unix, awk, sed, jq

I need to know all IP range (ip_prefix), associated with us-west-2 region only from this link - https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json (it can be opened in wordpad for better visibility)
Please suggest, how would I do it. If vi, awk or sed is needed, I have downloaded it on my linux server.

Thanks

Comment: It is bad form to only include a link to your data.  Provide a minimal snippet of the input directly in the question.

Comment: If you're dealing with structured data like JSON, don't parse it as if it's plain text.  Either read it into a program or use a tool like `jq` below.

Answer (score 1):

Use `jq` to parse json:

```
jq -r '.prefixes[] | select(.region == "us-west-2") | .ip_prefix' input-file
```

Comment: I will take care in future, to include more details as suggested. But your solution solved my purpose. Thanks